# Closer for measureToolTip, openLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, overlay, measurements

I want to add for my map measure tools. I added distance for line and square for polygon. Also i added erase for drawed element, but i  can't to clear measureTooltip. First I try do it with `Overlay.clear()`, but it results, that my popup destroy too. Second, I try remove html element through class, but don't have any reaction. Then I try do it like `popup.hide()`  window, but it's not effective. May be anybody have implemention for this task or you can modify my code.

```
lineDraw.on('drawstart', function(evt){
    sketch = evt.feature;
    var tooltipCoord = evt.coordinate;
    listener = sketch.getGeometry().on('change', function(evt) {
      var geom = evt.target;
      var output;
      output = formatLength((geom));
      tooltipCoord = geom.getLastCoordinate();
      measureTooltipElement.innerHTML = output;
      measureTooltip.setPosition(tooltipCoord);
    });
  }, this);

lineDraw.on('drawend', function(evt){
    measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-static';
    measureTooltip.setOffset([0, -7]);
    sketch = null;
    measureTooltipElement = null;
    createMeasureTooltip();
    ol.Observable.unByKey(listener);
}, this);

***

$("#drawLine").click(function() {
    clearCustomInteractions();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    map.addInteraction(lineDraw);
});

$("#drawPoly").click(function() {
    clearCustomInteractions();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    map.addInteraction(polyDraw);
});


$("#erase").click(function() {
    clearCustomInteractions();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    map.addInteraction(erase);

    erase.getFeatures().on('change:length', function(e){
        if(e.target.getArray().length  !== 0) {
            drawLayer.getSource().removeFeature(e.target.item(0));
        }
    });

    return false;
});

***

function clearCustomInteractions(){
$("#bar").find('p').removeClass('active');
map.removeInteraction(lineDraw);
map.removeInteraction(polyDraw);
}


function createMeasureTooltip() {
// if (measureTooltipElement) {
// measureTooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
//}
measureTooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
measureTooltipElement.className = 'tooltip tooltip-measure';

closer = document.createElement('a');
closer.href= '#';
closer.className = 'tooltip-closer tooltip-closer:after';
$(".tooltip").append($(closer));
measureTooltip = new ol.Overlay({
element: measureTooltipElement,
offset: [0, -15],
positioning: 'bottom-center'
});

map.addOverlay(measureTooltip);

}

closer.onclick = function() {
measureTooltip.style.display = 'none';
closer.blur();
return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have interest of this task, i realized this follow method:

```
$("#erase").click(function() {
    clearCustomInteractions();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    map.addInteraction(erase);

    erase.getFeatures().on('change:length', function(e){

        if(e.target.getArray().length  !== 0) {
            var i = e.target.item(0);
            var k = drawLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
            var j = k.indexOf(i);           
            drawLayer.getSource().removeFeature(e.target.item(0));
            delOverlay = map.getOverlays().array_[j+1];
            map.removeOverlay(delOverlay);
        }
    });
```

Comment this code: When you choose erase and distinguish some feature, (for example line), program find index of this element in array of features and delete overlay = thisIndexfeature + 1, because in array of overlays index[0] = popup.